# How to encode Ctrl characters in XML

Tags: xml, character, ctrl

I am trying to encode <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> character in xml file but its not being recognized as an ctrl character instead as a string

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>textinputformat.record.delimiter</name>
    <value>\u0003</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using a character entity should achieve this : `&#x0003;`

Note: this won't possible in XML 1.0, see  [XML recommendation, §2.2 Characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)
Control characters, among others, are not allowed.

Comment: @Paul Crovella You are right, I modified the answer. Thanks you for your remark.

Comment: using like that throws me below exception

ERROR ipc.RPC: FailoverProxy: Failing this Call: submitJob for error(RemoteException): org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#3" is an invalid XML character.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:4526)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

Comment: In XML 1.1, `&#x0003;` (or equivalently `&#x3;`) is permitted, but XML 1.1 has remained much less important than XML 1.0. What matters is what kind of XML processor will be used to process the data, i.e. will it accept and properly process (whatever that is) control characters.