# Can I put NUL (\x00) in xml

Tags: xml

Is it possible to put NUL(\x00) to xml ? I want to set it to a xml configuration as a separator e.g.,

```
<...separator="\x00" .../>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are "control" characters illegal in XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107/why-are-control-characters-illegal-in-xml)

Comment: This one as well deals with characters in XML [How to encode Ctrl characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598087/how-to-encode-ctrl-characters-in-xml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, NUL are not allowed in XML. Neither in XML 1.0, nor in XML 1.1.

Refer to XML recommendations :

- For XML 1.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets
- For XML 1.1 http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets

A difference between the two versions: in XML 1.1 it is allowed to insert control characters, but NUL (x0) remains forbidden.